# Create a global filter in JBoss 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, servlet-filters

I want to create a global custom filter, that catches(for checking/modification etc) http-headers for all web-applications on server.
I tryied to apply my filter as a global-module in standalone.xml, but it doesn't work

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.1">  
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>  
            <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>  
            <global-modules>  
                 <module name="com.myfilter.filter" slot="main"/>  
            </global-modules>  
</subsystem>
```

Help me please!

Comment: Global filters were initially not included in AS7. It was restricted to application level only (eg. jboss-web.xml per application). I do not remember which version it got added, perhaps try AS 7.3 or wildfly8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global module will only add something to global class path, it will not use it for requests.

What you request is outside Java EE specification. Some servers support such a functionality as an extension to the spec. Tomcat and JBoss have such extended support using Valves. You should be able to do what you're after by implementing a [Tomcat Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/Valve.html), installing it as a module and then configuring it to JBoss like [instructed here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web-server/using-web-valves-with-jboss-7):

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.4" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <valve name="myvalve" module="org.jboss.web-valves" class-name="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve">
        <param param-name="prefix" param-value="catalina_access_log."/>
        <param param-name="suffix" param-value=".txt"/>
    </valve>
            . . . .
</subsystem>
```